# Obter retorno de função dentro de um getter do Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-eventos, vuex, getters

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o bind rules do vuetify e nele um metodo que vem de dentro de um getter em um modulo. no bind o metodo retorna da melhor forma possivel, me dando error ou succes e a mensagem que determinei a dúvida é a seguinte, como eu leio o valor retornado fora deste bind?

O bind é o seguinte

```
:rules="[ InputRules('required'), InputRules('email') ]"
```

Caso não digite nada, a mensagem do required aparece (obrigatório) e caso o email não esteja no formado do regex então a mensagem de email inválido aparece, neste ponto, tudo funciona muito bem, minha única dúvida é quando eu quero reaproveitar a função, eu quero saber quando ela retornará Booleam ou Function utilizando o `contructor`ou algo parecido, o problema é, se eu coloco em um `console` desta forma

```
console.log(this.InputRules('email'))
```

só me retorna este

```
ƒ (value) {
      return /^(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)*@(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}\b)+$/i.test(value) || text || 'E-mail inválido';
    }
```

tentei várias formas, como adicionar o constructor no final mas não me retorna nada além de `undefined`
como fazer para receber se o valor é o texto ou não, ou seja, o caso `false` é o texto e o caso true é o Boolean (no caso, o `false` que ele retorna no bind do rule)

o meu getter é este

```
const InputRules = () => (rule, text) => {
  if (rule === 'required') return value => !!value || (text || 'Obrigatório')
  if (rule === 'email') return value => /^(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)*@(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}\b)+$/i.test(value) || (text || 'E-mail inválido')
}
```

percebi que isso

```
console.log([this.InputRules('email', value)])
```

me retorna algumas informações como o campo e tal.

---

> Solução para aqueles que precisarem

Basta trocar o retorno da function, se passar isso

```
if (rule === 'email') return value => /^(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)*@(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}\b)+$/i.test(value) || (text || 'E-mail inválido')
```

para isso

```
if (rule === 'email') {
    return (() => {
      return /^(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)*@(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}\b)+$/i.test(value) || (text || 'E-mail inválido')
    })(text, value)
  }
```

pronto, isso retornará String ou Boolean, String para Fail e Boolean para Success, agora basta chamar o getter no :rule de forma normal e no succes comparar o constructor

Comment: Roberto, seria legal você colocar a solução que você achou como uma resposta e aceitá-la como correta. É melhor do que adicionar a solução dentro da pergunta.

Comment: entendo, achei que não seria uma boa prática, visto que não sei se a minha solução é a mais correta e deixei em aberto para uma solução melhor de alguém mais experiente.

Comment: Você pode deixar a resposta por um tempo sem aceitá-la como correta, então se ninguém responder você aceita. O importante é que fique correto como uma resposta para que fique mais fácil de achar... Tem na ajuda do site: [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

> Solução para aqueles que precisarem

Basta trocar o retorno da function, se passar isso

```
if (rule === 'email') return value => /^(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)*@(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}\b)+$/i.test(value) || (text || 'E-mail inválido')
```

para isso

```
if (rule === 'email') {
    return (() => {
      return /^(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)*@(\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\b)(\.\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}\b)+$/i.test(value) || (text || 'E-mail inválido')
    })(text, value)
  }
```

pronto, isso retornará String ou Boolean, String para Fail e Boolean para Success, agora basta chamar o getter no :rule de forma normal e no succes comparar o constructor